# copy 2 arrays into 1 array, in C prog

Tags: c, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

**How can i copy 2 seperate 2D arrays into 1 array, i have described below what i mean:**

I have 1 array: a, b, c
I have a second array: d, e, f

I want the third array to have both the above arrays:
3rd array: a, b, c, d, e, f

So far my code is just taking values for both arrays and i commented out when printing the 3rd array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int i,j,count;

    char ar1[3][10]={"a","b","c"};
    char ar2[3][10]={"d","e","f"};
    char ar3[6][10];

    for (i=0;i<3;i++){
        printf("%s\n",ar1[i]);
    }
    for (i=0;i<3;i++){
        printf("%s\n",ar2[i]);
    }
    printf('new array:\n');
//  for (i=0;i<6;i++)
//      printf("%s\t\n",ar3[i]);
}
```

Comment: What did you try, when it comes to the actual copying?

Comment: Where are you initializing your arr3 or copying items to arr3 ?

Comment: Have you tried the function strcat?

Comment: i tried strcpy which causes the system to crash @Lundin

Comment: Show what you tried. We can't help if we don't know what is wrong.

Comment: @Gopi so far my code just inputs letters to the 1st 2 arrays, i dont know how to copy items into arr3

Comment: @Quest you copy the 2 arrays into the third array by using a for loop. So first you will copy the first array into ar3 and then you will copy the second array. So you will need two for loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the right most dimensions of the arrays are equal then the simplest way to copy two arrays in one is the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char ar1[3][10] = { "a", "b", "c" };
    char ar2[3][10] = { "d", "e", "f" };
    char ar3[6][10];

    memcpy( ar3, ar1, sizeof( ar1 ) );
    memcpy( ar3 + 3, ar2, sizeof( ar2 ) );  

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 6; i++ )
    {
        puts( ar3[i] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

The other approach is to copy each string separatly using function `strcpy`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char ar1[3][10] = { "a", "b", "c" };
    char ar2[3][10] = { "d", "e", "f" };
    char ar3[6][10];

    size_t j = 0;
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++, j++ )
    {
        strcpy( ar3[j], ar1[i] );
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++, j++ )
    {
        strcpy( ar3[j], ar2[i] );
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 6; i++ )
    {
        puts( ar3[i] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output will be the same as above

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

Comment: using the 1st code you have, if i get empty lines, blank lines with values spaced out.....how can i fix this by removing blank lines

Comment: @Quest In this case you should use the second approach copying each line separatly by means of strcpy.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be something like

```
for (i=0;i<3;i++){
       ar3[i][0] = ar1[i][0];
}
for (i=0;i<3;i++){
    ar3[i+3][0] = ar2[i][0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From people's comments its seems it works like this. **Question: is there a way where i don't have to specify "i+3" i.e. can i append the 2 arrays together? so it directly prints 1 after the other**.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>





    int main()
    {
        int i,j,count;


   char ar1[3][10]={"a","b","c"};
   char ar2[3][10]={"d","e","f"};
   char ar3[6][10];

        for (i=0;i<3;i++){
            printf("%s\n",ar1[i]);
            strcpy(ar3[i],ar1[i]);

        }
        for (i=0;i<3;i++){
            printf("%s\n",ar2[i]);
            strcpy(ar3[i+3],ar2[i]);
        }


    //  printf('new array:\n');
        for (i=0;i<6;i++)
            printf("%s\t\n",ar3[i]);
    }
```