# RE: remove empty lines/blank strings from array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

Regarding @Vlad from Moscow's code: 
[copy 2 arrays into 1 array, in C prog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26714225/copy-2-arrays-into-1-array-in-c-prog/26714792#26714792)

**Does anyone know how to remove empty lines if his code is edited in this manner:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
size_t i;
    char ar1[3][10]={"a","b","c"};
    char ar2[3][10]={"d","e","f"};
    char ar3[10][10];

    memcpy( ar3, ar1, sizeof( ar1 ) );
    memcpy( ar3 + 5, ar2, sizeof( ar2 ) );  

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    {
        puts( ar3[i] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all, make sure that `ar3` is fully initialized, then just add a check for it.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.  Remove the "lines" from the array in the program memory?  Remove something from the output?

Comment: @Vorsprung remove the empty lines in the output, so it only prints the elements with values in them

Comment: @Quest Sis you specially write  memcpy( ar3 + 5, ar2, sizeof(  ar2 ) );  instead of memcpy( ar3 + 3, ar2, sizeof(  ar2 ) );? That is why are you using 5 instead of 3 in expression ar3 + 5?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow i did that intentionally, i wanted a way to only print string values and skip empty values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how it can be done

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t remove_blank( char ( *s )[10], size_t n )
{
    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i < n && !( s[i][0] == '\0' ) ) ++i;

    for ( size_t j = i + 1; j < n; j++ )
    {
        if ( s[j][0] != '\0' )
        {
            strcpy( s[i], s[j] );
            ++i;
        }
    }

    for( size_t j = i; j < n; j++ ) s[j][0] = '\0';

    return i;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char ar1[3][10]={"a","b","c"};
    char ar2[3][10]={"d","e","f"};
    char ar3[10][10] = { { '\0' } };;

    size_t j = 0;
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++, j++ )
    {
        strcpy( ar3[j], ar1[i] );
    }

    j += 2;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++, j++ )
    {
        strcpy( ar3[j], ar2[i] );
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    {
        puts( ar3[i] );
    }

    size_t n = remove_blank( ar3, 10 );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        puts( ar3[i] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
a
b
c


d
e
f


a
b
c
d
e
f
```

The same can be done for your approach of copying arrays. The only requirements is that `ar3`shall be zero-initialized

```
char ar3[10][10] = { { '\0' } };
```